# PHP Laravel project gives 403 forbidden

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have a project `xyz` in directory `var/www/html/xyz` and the project structure is like the `xyz` itself have multiple laravel projects created in it as:

```
    var/www/html/xyz/public_site
    var/www/html/xyz/admin
    var/www/html/xyz/frontend
    var/www/html/xyz/api
    .
    .
    .
```

and all of these are combined as `xyz` and it runs as a single project, some of them are having only frontend having vue.js and some projects are serving as backend or api's. Now, firstly i don't know how to run this type of project as some of the internal projects are only having vue components. What i have tried so far is creating a virtualhost on apache2 in ubuntu and when i run `xyz.local` it works fine but when i access `admin` project as `xyz.local/admin` apache gives 403 forbidden on this URL.

Virtualhost is created as follows:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@xyz
    ServerName xyz.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/xyz.com/public_html/

    <Directory /var/www/html/xyz.com/public_html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

and there is the .htaccess file in public_html project folder as follows:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    #Rewrite requests to the S3 bucket
    

   
    #Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    #Handle Front Controller...
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/opelia [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/check-in [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/callsearch [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/security-app [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/delivery-app [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/social [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    #Handle Admin Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/opelia [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/check-in [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/callsearch [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/security-app [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/delivery-app [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/social [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ admin.php [L]

    #Handle API Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/opelia [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/v2 [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/check-in [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/callsearch [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/security-app [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/delivery-app [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/social [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ api.php [L]

    #Handle adminRestaurant Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/check-in [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/callsearch [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/security-app [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/delivery-app [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/social [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ adminRest.php [L]

    #Handle APIV2 Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/opelia [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/check-in [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/callsearch [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/security-app [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/delivery-app [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/v2 [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/social [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads [NC]
    RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ apiV2.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]


    #Handle Checkin App Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/opelia [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/v2 [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/callsearch [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/security-app [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/delivery-app [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/check-in [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/social [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ check-in.php [L]

    #Handle Callsearch App Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/opelia [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/v2 [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/check-in [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/security-app [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/delivery-app [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/social [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ callsearch.php [L]

    #Handle Callsearch App Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/opelia [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/v2 [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/check-in [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/callsearch [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/delivery-app [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/social [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ security-app.php [L]

    #Handle Delivery App Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/opelia [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/v2 [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/check-in [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/callsearch [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/security-app [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/social [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ delivery-app.php [L]

    #Handle Social App Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/opelia [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/v2 [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/check-in [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/callsearch [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/security-app [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/delivery-app [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ social.php [L]


    RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ https://xyz-files-new.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/$1[R=301,L]
    #Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    </IfModule>


    #php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
    #Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
    <IfModule mime_module>
    #AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
    #AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php .php5 .phtml
    </IfModule>
    #php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

and apache's `error.log` has following:

```
   Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:54374] AH00035: access to /admin denied (filesystem path '/var/www/html/xyz.com/public_html') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

Comment: Is this a PHP problem, an Apache problem, or a Ubuntu problem? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck? Does the server's error log contain more details?

Comment: This is not a PHP problem, it's configuration problem of the project to run with apache2.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If this is not related to PHP, remove that tag

Comment: @NicoHaase already added.